# Pandas if statement for finding substring in string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following column:

```
print(df):
Name
James#4567547
Mick#5456535
Tash
Liv#5468646
Nathan
Chris
```

You wil see some rows have the `#` and some dont. How can I loop through and retain all names and remove the `#` if present and anything after it. To get:

```
print(df):
Name
James
Mick
Tash
Liv
Nathan
Chris
```

I have tried:

```
if df['Name'].str.contains('#').any():
    df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.split('#',1)[0]

else:
    df['Name'] = df['Name']
```

But am getting a `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index` at the `str.split` line. Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one would be good for `str.split()`, and this is the syntax.

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.split('#').str[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way. Use regex to read the suffix and replace it using the `.str.replace()` method

```
df.Name=df.Name.str.replace('[\#\d+]','')

    Name
0   James
1   Mick
2   Tash
3   Liv
4   Nathan
5   Chris
```